# (J2ME) How to get list of files/resources inside my jar app

Tags: java, file, java-me

So, I am creating a mobile application using j2me and lwuit.
In that application the user will open a file.

My question is how do I get list of files inside my jar application..

Ex : Inside a res folder there are :

File1.fl,
File2.fl,
File3.fl,

We can open a single file using `getResourceAsStream()` function. 
But how do I get the list of file names inside the folder.

I came across with `FileConnection` but it seems that it is used to access files in the local phone.

In java we can do this using the `File` class.. Anyone can help me with these...
Thanks guys..

Comment: why you are storing the files inside Jar file ?

Comment: I made a story reader app that display list of story.. 
I stored the application title in a recordStore with string of each file respective folder which I keep inside my packages.. I split one story into several parts and put them together in one folder.. So instead of storing each part link file inside a recordstore, I intend just to get list of file inside the folder and put them on display for the user to choose..

Answer (score 1):

This works for applets, at least:

```
ClassLoader cl = getClass().getClassLoader();
URL url = cl.getResource("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");  /* just a random file that's known to exist */
JarURLConnection conn = (JarURLConnection)url.openConnection();
JarFile jar = conn.getJarFile();
Enumeration e = jar.entries();
```

Then you have to go through the enumeration and select the appropriate items. Note that the entries will be full pathnames inside the jar, and that directories may not be present as their own entries, but only as part of the pathname of the files contained within.