# Iterate thru resources inside folder in j2me

Tags: java-me, resources, iteration

How do I iterate through the resources in a folder inside the jar?

I want to do Image.createImage(name) many times, so I only need the list of names. Do I need to use (FileConnection)Connector.open? I couldn't do that without access to root, and without that, how can I know the path of my application in the end machine?

This solution proposes ClassLoader, which is not in the j2me, and was not answered anymore:
[(J2ME) How to get list of files/resources inside my jar app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251669/j2me-how-to-get-list-of-files-resources-inside-my-jar-app)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should add the location of files into your classpath of JAR execution.

Comment: I tried System.getProperty("java.class.path"). It returns null, because my application is unsigned, I guess. It invalidates your approach? If I got it right, why would I need to know the external path, if the images are inside my jar app? I can use a text file to put all the names, but what if the files were created at runtime, so I don't have their names?

Comment: How do I know why is this -1 in my question?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't understand what Bhavik meant. I found a workaround, creating a txt file with the names of the png images. I still don't know how to iterate through res folder inside the jar, though:

```
  InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Aves/dir.txt");
  int ch, isp=0;
  String l = "";
  do {
    ch = is.read();
    if ((ch != 13) && (ch != 10)) {
      l+=(char)ch;
    } else {
      if (ch == 13) {
        Image Img1 = Image.createImage("/Aves/"+l);
        sppW[isp] = Img1.getWidth();
        sppH[isp] = Img1.getHeight();
        Img1.getRGB(sppImg[isp], 0, Img1.getWidth(), 0, 0, Img1.getWidth(), Img1.getHeight());
        isp++;
        l = "";
      }
    }
  } while (ch != -1);
```